# Asp.net core Entity Framework 6 error with multiple key entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hello I'm making a web app for events in my city (university homework)

I don't know why but I'm not getting what I want with EF. An event has schedules, and a user can join one shedule and rate it. I don't know why but my model doesn't work (count users in a schedule with users returns 0) also in the table dbo.UserJoinSchedule there is a column of type date... what I am doing wrong?

```
public class UserJoinEvent{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }

    [Range( 0, DomainConstraints.VoteMax )]
    public virtual int? Vote { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(DomainConstraints.ReviewMaxLen)]
    public virtual string Review { get; set; }
}

 public class Schedule{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public virtual DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserJoinEvent> UserJoined { get; set; }
}

public class Event{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MinLength(DomainConstraints.EventNameMinLen)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual double Latitude { get; set; }
    public virtual double Longitude { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection< Schedule > Schedule { get; set; }

    public virtual int EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection< UserJoinEvent > UserJoined { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder){
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity< Event >( e => e.HasMany( o => o.Schedule ).WithOne( o => o.Event ) );
        builder.Entity< Event >( e => e.HasMany( o => o.UserJoined ).WithOne( o => o.Event ).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict) );

        builder.Entity< EventType >( e => e.HasMany( o => o.Events ).WithOne( o => o.EventType ) );

        builder.Entity< Schedule >( e => e.HasKey( o => new {o.EventId, o.DateTime} ) );
        builder.Entity< Schedule >( e => e.HasMany( o => o.UserJoined ).WithOne( o => o.Schedule ).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict));

        builder.Entity< UserJoinEvent >( e => e.HasKey( o => new {o.EventId, o.ApplicationUserId} ) );

        builder.Entity< ApplicationUser >( e => e.HasMany( o => o.UserJoined ).WithOne( o => o.ApplicationUser ).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict));
    }

public enum Role { User, Mod, Admin }

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser{
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserJoinEvent> UserJoined { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
var @event = await _context.Events.Include( e => e.ApplicationUser ).Include( e => e.EventType ).Include( e => e.Schedule ).ThenInclude( uj => uj.UserJoined )
            .Include( e => e.UserJoined )
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

View:

```
@foreach( var s in Model.Schedule ) {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">@s.DateTime</div>
                    <div class="col-md-5"><b>Partecipanti:</b> @s.UserJoined.Count</div>
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: There really isn't enough information here for anyone to help you.  You  mention UserJoinSchedule, but that table nor User is even shown on here anywhere. Also, when you are doing the query, you need to do .Include() to select the sub records below the top or you have to use lazy loading (not recommended) in order to get those values back out.  Otherwise, it will always be 0.  However, we don't even see the call to the database you are making here...

Comment: ok I've added the requested information, and yes I'm using lazy loading...
I think that there is a problem in my Model since there is this additional key in the table UserJoinedEvent.
I've tryed to post a review in a schedule but still say 0 partecipants for that schedule (the review it's posted correctly and it is shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed, I am stupid! I wanted a unique key on Schedule not a primary

I solved removing:

```
builder.Entity< Schedule >( e => e.HasKey( o => new {o.EventId, o.DateTime} ) );
```

and adding:

```
 builder.Entity< Schedule >( e => e.HasAlternateKey( o => new {o.EventId, o.DateTime} ) );
```